# Recursion return 0 instead of 2?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I try to solve the challenge of how many symbols should be deleted from the string to make the string does not have matching adjacent characters, for example I have a string `AABA` one `A` should be deleted from it and after deletion it looks `ABA`, for the `AAAAB` 3 'A' symbols should be deleted to `AB` and difference variants of it.

I made decision to solve it with recursion:

```js
function solution(s, isA = s[0] === "A", count = 0) {
  if ((typeof s === "string" && !s.includes("B")) || !s.includes("A")) {
    return s.length - 1;
  }

  const strArr = Array.isArray(s) ? s : s.split("");
  const currentSymbol = strArr.shift();

  if ((currentSymbol === "A" && isA) || (currentSymbol === "B" && !isA)) {
    return solution(strArr, false, count);
  }

  if ((currentSymbol === "A" && !isA) || (currentSymbol === "B" && isA)) {
    return solution(strArr, false, ++count);
  }

  return count;
}

console.log(solution("AAAB"));
```

While debugging for `AAAB` string the count equals 2 but at the last moment it becomes 0 (first value in the call stack), how can I solve it ?

Comment: Shouldn't `return s.length - 1;` be `return count`? I don't see why you'd ever want to return something other than `count` here, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: A non recursive solution with regex: `"AAAB".replace(/(.)\1+/g, '$1')`

Comment: Is `BB` to be replaced with `B`? Is there any given list of _symbols_ to be replaced or should any multiply repeated characters be replaced?

Comment: @uladz  You are trying to recreate something like an regular expression engine on a very low level. If you want to do it for fun, that's ok. But if you want to find a solution to your problem. I'd recommend you learn regular expressions

Comment: @yunzen Yes, it's trivial with regex but I think even a simple loop is sufficient. I have trouble understanding how this this algorithm is supposed to work and I don't think recursion would be my first choice here, either. Ultimately, this is a matter of finding sequences of linear characters, so basing this on a linear scan (a loop) seems like the most obvious choice to start with.

Comment: @VLAZ this checking will work only once at the first time, later i convert string into array and work with array

Comment: @yunzen i do it for fun, I will learn regex 100%, but now i need to know why this recursion doesn't work.

Comment: @UladzKha I understand that. I'm not sure how the recursion is used and what the original idea is. I see the problem but I am not sure how to solve it while still keeping to the intended approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**know your ancestors**

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutations, variable reassignments, and other side effects.

1. If the first character, `s0`, is not present, the base case has been reached. Return the empty result.
2. (inductive) the first character is *not* null. If it is equal to the next character, `s1`, these two characters are adjacent duplicates. Discard the first character and return the result of the sub-problem `[s1, ...s]`.
3. (inductive) the first character is not null and it does *not* equal the second character. These two characters are not duplicates. Append the first character to the result of the sub-problem, `[s1, ...s]`.

```js
function removeAdjacentDuplicates ([s0, s1, ...s])
{ if (s0 == null)
    return ""                                        // #1
  else if (s0 == s1)
    return removeAdjacentDuplicates([s1, ...s])      // #2
  else
    return s0 + removeAdjacentDuplicates([s1, ...s]) // #3
}

console.log(removeAdjacentDuplicates("AAABBCCCDDDEEEEE"))
// ABCDE

console.log(removeAdjacentDuplicates("ABBXYY"))
// ABXY

console.log(removeAdjacentDuplicates("LMNOP"))
// LMNOP
```

Building complex programs in functional style is a matter of composing several simple programs together. To get the answer to your question we can write `solution` as follows -

```js
const solution = s =>
  s.length - removeAdjacentDuplicates(s).length

console.log(solution("AAABBCCCDDDEEEEE")) // 11
console.log(solution("ABBXYY"))           // 2
console.log(solution("LMNOP"))            // 0
```

Expand the snippet below to verify the results in your own browser -

```js
function removeAdjacentDuplicates ([s0, s1, ...s])
{ if (s0 == null)
    return ""
  else if (s0 == s1)
    return removeAdjacentDuplicates([s1, ...s])
  else
    return s0 + removeAdjacentDuplicates([s1, ...s])
}

const solution = s =>
  s.length - removeAdjacentDuplicates(s).length
  
console.log(solution("AAABBCCCDDDEEEEE")) // 11
console.log(solution("ABBXYY"))           // 2
console.log(solution("LMNOP"))            // 0
```

```js
11
2
0
```

---

**reduce, simplify**

After we have identified the logical structure of `removeAdjacentDuplicates` we can use logical transforms to manipulate it, the same way we use laws to transform a mathematical formula. Below we collapse two of the logical branches into one to reduce a bit of code duplication -

```js
function removeAdjacentDuplicates ([s0, s1, ...s])
{ if (s0 == null)
    return ""    
  else
    return (s0 == s1 ? "" : s0)
      + removeAdjacentDuplicates([s1, ...s])
}

console.log(removeAdjacentDuplicates("AAABBCCCDDDEEEEE"))
// ABCDE

console.log(removeAdjacentDuplicates("ABBXYY"))
// ABXY

console.log(removeAdjacentDuplicates("LMNOP"))
// LMNOP
```

---

**one function, please!**

We could write everything as one big function, if we wanted, but this goes against functional style. In the implementation above, `removeAdjacentDuplicates` is a useful function on its own. It was easy to write and likewise `solution` was easy to write thanks to the separation of our program's multiple concerns. As a bonus, the separated functions can be reused in other programs.

Below, `solution` is rewritten as a single function and its intentions are now less clear. It's harder to write, harder to debug, and not easily reused in other programs -

```js
function solution ([s0, s1, ...s], n = 0)
{ if (s0 == null)
    return n
  else
    return solution([s1, ...s], n + Number(s0 == s1))
}

console.log(solution("AAABBCCCDDDEEEEE"))
// 11

console.log(solution("ABBXYY"))
// 2

console.log(solution("LMNOP"))
// 0
```

---

**one expression, please!**

Another variant is available to us that trades the tail-recursive form for a tree-recursive form. The exchange reveals a form that does not need an extra parameter with a default argument -

```js
function solution ([s0, s1, ...s])
{ if (s0 == null)
    return 0
  else
    return Number(s0 == s1) + solution([s1, ...s])
}
```

As Scott points out, this is one syntax transformation away from a singular, pure functional expression -

```js
const countAdjacentDuplicates = ([s0, s1, ...s]) =>
  s0 == null
    ? 0
    : Number(s0 == s1) + countAdjacentDuplicates([s1, ...s])

console.log(countAdjacentDuplicates("AAABBCCCDDDEEEEE"))
// 11

console.log(countAdjacentDuplicates("ABBXYY"))
// 2

console.log(countAdjacentDuplicates("LMNOP"))
// 0
```

In a way, this dissolves some of the lesson I was trying to teach, but hopefully you were still able to learn something from this post.

Comment: The only pain I see in that final version (besides meaningless function name inherited from the question) is in `n + Number (s0 == s1)`.  If it used instead `n + (s0 == s1 ? 1 : 0)`, it would be perfectly expressive to me.  Of course it would be even clearer without the tail-call affordances.  But one day, if we're lucky, those will truly be important.

Comment: That is, I find this version quite clear: `const countAdjDups = ([s0, s1, ...ss]) => s0 == null ? 0 : (s0 == s1 ? 1 : 0) + countAdjDups ([s1, ... ss])`.  None of this should take away from the fact that this is an excellent answer.

Comment: thanks for the feedback Scott. `bool->number` conversion should be straightforward, i think, but your ternary expression maybe a little more spelled out. your recursive expression is nice and i suppose i _should_ offer it as an alternative... even if it is to the detriment of the lesson i am trying to teach. gotta remain objective! lmao

Comment: The lesson seems to assume that there is a more important goal of actually removing duplicate characters.  Sometimes that is the case, and a counting exercise, as you show, can be built atop a function which does the real work.  But that's not always the case.  The problem of counting the number of legal arrangements of `n` pairs of parentheses (the [Catalan Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number)) is a very different, though related, problem from that of actually *producing* those arrangements (e.g. for `3`, they would be `()()()`, `()(())`, `(())())`, `(()())` and `((()))`).

Comment: i hear ya re: counting them vs actually doing the work to remove them. i typically lean towards the decomposed approach as a single function mixes counting with the actual work to compute them. this is the primary reason you see me using generators in many of my newer works as it pushes the user's intended effect to the farthest edges of our program. consider this [very relevant Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66171502/how-to-return-a-list-of-a-recursive-function-in-python/66173738#66173738) posted just moments after this answer.

Comment: That question is schizophrenic about whether it wants the values or a count of them, and your answer does a good job with both. If you just wanted a count, an implementation like `const countNo00 = (n) =>  n <= 0 ? 1 : countNo00(n - 1) + countNo00(n - 2)` could quickly let you realize that the problem is related to Fibonacci numbers, which might be hidden by a function like `const findNo00 = (n) => n <= 1 ? [''] : [...findNo00 (n - 1) .map (s => '1' + s), ...findNo00 (n - 2) .map (s => '01' + s)]`. I'm just saying that sometimes counting atop building is important, sometimes it's overkill.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```js
function solution(s, i = 0, count = 0) {
  let pre = "";

  if(i>=1 && s[i-1] === s[i]) {
    count++;
  }

  if(s.length>i+1) {
    return solution(s,i+1,count);
  }

  return count;
}

console.log(solution("AAAB"));
```