# Turning a while loop to a recursion

Tags: python, loops, recursion

I'm trying to turn this code ( that gives the maximum number of consecutive 0's in a binary) to a recursive code. I tried in many ways but the result is wrong.
This is the code using a while loop :

```py
def consecutivezeros(N):
    if N==0 :
        return 1
    # variable to store the length
    # of longest consecutive 0's
    maxm = -1

    # to temporary store the
    # consecutive 0's
    cnt = 0
    while (N):
        if (not (N & 1)):
            cnt += 1
            N >>= 1
            maxm = max(maxm, cnt)
        else:
            maxm = max(maxm, cnt)
            cnt = 0
            N >>= 1

    return maxm
```

Comment: I dont think that recursion can be of use in this method. that path your code is following is linear, and so recursion won't fit nicely to solve it. why do you want to use  recursion?

Comment: A better naming scheme could go a long way in making this easier to rewrite. Is ``N`` an input ``number``? Is ``maxm`` the ``maximum_count``, and ``cnt`` the ``current_count``? In how far have you "tried in many ways but the result is wrong."?

Comment: @idik Google "tail recursion", which is likely the intended outcome of this exercise.

Comment: i have to use recursion for an exercise , i have to write ONE function that takes a integer N and have to return the the maximum number of consecutive 0's in the binary form of N. And it have to be done in a recursive way :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the principled way:

```
def consecutivezeros(N):
    if N == 0:
        return 1
    def _consecutivezeros(N, maxm, cnt):
        if not N:
            return maxm
        elif (not (N & 1)):
            new_cnt = cnt + 1
            return _consecutivezeros(N>>1, max(maxm, new_cnt), new_cnt)
        else:
            return _consecutivezeros(N>>1, max(maxm, cnt), 0)
    return _consecutivezeros(N, -1, 0)
```

Here is the dumb, unprincipled way, basically just use a recursive helper function that mutates variables in it's closure, this is just to demonstrate how recursion can basically replace a while-loop directly, but it's not very elegant:

```
def consecutivezeros(N):
    if N == 0:
        return 1
    maxm = -1
    cnt = 0
    def _looper():
        nonlocal maxm, cnt, N
        if not N:
            return
        if (not (N & 1)):
            cnt += 1
            maxm = max(maxm, cnt)
        else:
            maxm = max(maxm, cnt)
            cnt = 0
        N >>= 1
    _looper(N)
    return maxm
```

EDIT:

If you don't want to use an auxilliary helper function, you need additional arguments:

```
def consecutivezeros(N, _maxm=-1, _cnt=0, _first=True):
    if N == 0 and _first:
        return 1
    elif not N:
        return _maxm
    elif (not (N & 1)):
        incr = _cnt + 1
        return consecutivezeros(N>>1, max(_maxm, incr), incr, False)
    else:
        return consecutivezeros(N>>1, max(_maxm, _cnt), 0, False)
```

Comment: the principled way works with the examples I have but does not work with N = 0 , 4 or 2 ,

Comment: another thing is that the exercise says that we don't have the right to create another function :/

Comment: @kr4t0s26 yeah it had a bug, it should work now

Comment: @kr4t0s26 well, you can still do it, but then your function need additional arguments, it's just cleaner to do it with a little helper function like that so as not to expose arguments that are implementation details and not really part of the API

Comment: right , they insisted on the fact that we can add as many arguments as we want to our function

Comment: @kr4t0s26 ok, well, I posted an example.

Comment: is there a way to write the princpled way with only the main function ?

Comment: @kr4t0s26 yes... I just showed how in my last edit

Comment: The unprincipled version could also mutate `N` for consistency. This way it's not clear why it passes `N` by value, but mutates all other "loop" variables.

Comment: @user4815162342 sure, but I was just demonstrating a point.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga That part is clear :) I was suggesting that the point would be even better demonstrated by mutating `N` as well.

Comment: what is the principle for the design?

Answer (score 0):

```
def rec_count(s: str, c: int = 0, m: int = 0):
    if s:
        if s[0] == "0":
            if (c := c+1) > m:
                m = c

            return rec_count(s[1:], m=m, c=c)
        else:
            return rec_count(s[1:], m=m)
    else:
        return m


N = 100000100101
print(rec_count(s=str(N)))
# 5
```

EDIT: According to comment, input is `int` instead of binary or `str`. Changed solution accordingly.

Comment: I just noticed, that I overread your mention of "consecutive 0s".

Comment: im sorry i didn't say this in my question : the N is an integer number not a binary one

Comment: You can transform an `int` into a `str` with `N_as_string = str(N)`.
EDIT: Added it to the original function.

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is a functional heritage and so using it with functional style yields the best results. This means avoiding things like mutations, variable reassignments and other side effects. We can use [inductive reasoning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction) to solve the problem in a principled way -

1. If the input, `n`, has only a single bit, the base case has been reached. Return the zero streak, `z`, if `n` is 1 or return `z` plus 1 for the final zero
2. (inductive) `n` has more than one bit remaining. If the first bit is a 1, the streak is broken. Yield the current zero streak, `z`, and recur on the sub-problem `n >> 1` with a fresh zero streak of 0
3. (inductive) `n` has more than one bit and the first bit is a 0. Recur on the sub-problem `n >> 1` with an incremented zero streak

```py
def consecutive_zeroes(n, z = 0):
  if n < 2:                                      # 1
    yield z if n == 1 else z + 1
  elif n & 1:                                    # 2
    yield z
    yield from consecutive_zeroes(n >> 1, 0)
  else:                                          # 3
    yield from consecutive_zeroes(n >> 1, z + 1)
```

Notice the generator is disentangled from the `max` logic. The built-in `max` function already accepts an iterable input, so there's little sense in duplicating that.

```py
for x in range(20):
  print(f"{x:b}", max(consecutive_zeroes(x)))
```

```
0 1
1 0
10 1
11 0
100 2
101 1
110 1
111 0
1000 3
1001 2
1010 1
1011 1
1100 2
1101 1
1110 1
1111 0
10000 4
10001 3
10010 2
10011 2
```

```py
for x in range(60, 80):
  print(f"{x:b}", max(consecutive_zeroes(x)))
```

```
111100 2
111101 1
111110 1
111111 0
1000000 6
1000001 5
1000010 4
1000011 4
1000100 3
1000101 3
1000110 3
1000111 3
1001000 3
1001001 2
1001010 2
1001011 2
1001100 2
1001101 2
1001110 2
1001111 2
```

```py
for x in range(500, 520):
  print(f"{x:b}", max(consecutive_zeroes(x)))
```

```
111110100 2
111110101 1
111110110 1
111110111 1
111111000 3
111111001 2
111111010 1
111111011 1
111111100 2
111111101 1
111111110 1
111111111 0
1000000000 9
1000000001 8
1000000010 7
1000000011 7
1000000100 6
1000000101 6
1000000110 6
1000000111 6
```

**prevent leaked parameters**

If you don't want extra parameters like `z` or expecting caller to require `max`, we can embed a nested helper, `loop`, in our function -

```py
def consecutive_zeroes(n):          # <- new wrapper, with no leaked parameters
  def loop(n, z):                   # <- our function above, renamed to loop
    if n < 2:
      yield z if n == 1 else z + 1
    elif n & 1:
      yield z
      yield from loop(n >> 1, 0)
    else:
      yield from loop(n >> 1, z + 1)
  return max(loop(n, 0))            # <- max
```

Now when you call it, `max` is no longer required by the caller -

```py
for x in range(20):
  print(f"{x:b}", consecutive_zeroes(x))   # <- no need to call max

# ...
```

**related Q&A**

- [How to find all numbers in a range without consecutive zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66173738/633183)